# How do I leftalign with amsmath?

Tags: align, amsmath

I use the command `\begin{align*}` but the left column does not align at the left side. How can I rectify this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Pro^i   &   \qquad Hello \\
Pro^{ii} &  \qquad Goodbye
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the intended behaviour. The `&` produces `right` `left` alignment. You have to use `&` suitably or use `alignat*` as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&Pro^i   &&   \qquad Hello \\
&Pro^{ii} &&  \qquad Goodbye
\end{align*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&Pro^i   &&   \qquad Hello \\
&Pro^{ii} &&  \qquad Goodbye
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume that `Pro` and `Hello` etc are just for demo. So I left them, otherwise you have to enclose them inside `\text` macro at least.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow \begin{alignat*} does not compile with me.

Comment: I use Pro^i and so on. Should I instead write \text{Pro^i}?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal It  depends on what kind of parameter `Pro` is. If it is text, use `\text{Pro}`.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal If they're names of variables, use `\mathit{Pro}^i`. If they're function names, possibly `\mathrm{Pro}^i`. Decide what you prefer, but definitely not for `Pro^i`.

Comment: @egreg These are names of some axiomatic principles. I liked \mathrm{Pro}^i.